# What is the best user-Id Value for a MySql "users" table

Tags: php, mysql

It may sounds trivial. but I want to know the Secure way of generating user-IDs to be used in MySql table. This is because I feel that using pure Integer IDs can enable hacking?.

Comment: Anything badly done "enables hacking", ints or no ints.

Comment: No, putting your database in public without firewalls and not paying attention to SQL injection enables hacking.

Comment: See perhaps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: ...but the best user-Id Value for a MySql “users” table is 81. But seriously, can you clarify how integers "enable hacking"?

Answer (score 4):

Everything can be hacked, the only difference is that if the ID is used as a parameter in the URL or any other input. Then a GUID could be better to use.

Example : url/?id=1.